# Prove that $p$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ if and only if $x^2+3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm having trouble with this particular homework problem. I think I have one direction:

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$. If $p$ is prime, then $p$ is irreducible in $R$, since $R$ is an integral domain. Thus, $(p)$ is maximal, so
$$
R/(p) \cong \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2+3)
$$
is a field. Hence, $(x^2+3)$ is maximal in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, so $x^2+3$ is irreducible.

However, if we assume $x^2+3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, then that only implies that $p$ is irreducible in $R$ by the same reasoning. Since $R$ isn't a UFD, this doesn't imply $p$ is prime, so I'm stuck.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Doesn't it imply that $(p)$ is maximal ideal in $R$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $R/(p)$ is a domain, then that *does* imply that $p$ is prime in $R$ ([see the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element)). In other words, an element is prime precisely when the ideal it generates is prime, which is the case precisely when quotienting by that ideal produces an integral domain. If you assume that $x^2+3$ is irreducible, then you have that
$$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]/(p)\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(p,x^2+3)\cong \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2+3)$$
is an integral domain (indeed, a field in this case).

Comment: Doesn't $p$ irreducible imply $p$ prime only in unique factorization domains?

Comment: No, it is more generally true in [GCD domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain) (and I'm not sure if this is necessary either); however, irreducibility is not the issue here.

Comment: Ahh, I see. The book I'm using is Artin, and he doesn't introduce prime ideals until the next chapter. Is there a similar argument that doesn't make use of them?

Comment: @N.S. No, for example $2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ but it is not prime because $(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$ is divisible by $2$ even though neither factor is.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Yea remembered it after posting... Anyhow, $(p)$ maximal implies $p$ prime element.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\rm\ R/p\, \cong\, S/q\  $ then $\rm\ p\: prime\ in\,R\!\iff\! domain\: R/p \,\cong\, S/q\!\iff\! q\: prime\ in\ S$